# Drupal 7 tabs activation using url

Tags: jquery, tabs, drupal-7

Drupal 7 has the field group module which contains a `horizontal_tab.js` file.

Inside this file i found this written

```
// If the current URL has a fragment and one of the tabs contains an
// element that matches the URL fragment, activate that tab.
if (window.location.hash && $(window.location.hash, this).length) {
   tab_focus = $(window.location.hash, this).closest('.horizontal-tabs-pane');
}
```

Can someone explain how this would work and what exact url i should call so that a particular tab is activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current url is something like `http://www.example.com/test.htm#part2:`

location.hash will give you the hash value
i.e `#part2`

From their comment.

```
// If the current URL has a fragment and one of the tabs contains an
// element that matches the URL fragment, activate that tab.
```

Means  if the hash value matches, they are trying to find the closest element with class

```
'.horizontal-tabs-pane'
```

If so they are focusing the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Our field_group module have one file with name modules/field_group/horizontal-tabs/horizontal-tabs.js

and in this file at line number 38 add this line  `alert(this.id)`  
Its print Id of perticular tab. After finding this id you can pass in your url with #(hash)

ex : `alert(this.id);`

After page URL add this ID with # sign so its by default open specified Tab

Combination of Id goes like this

Syntax  => `node_YourContentTypeName_full_group_YourFieldName`

Example => `node_product_full_group_item_name`

here product is content type and item_name is field name